# Finding the rate of change of an exponential growth problem.

Tags: calculus

In 1980 the world population was approximately 4.5 billion and in the year 2000 it was approximately 6 billion. Assume that the world population at each time increases at a rate proportional to the population at time t. Measure t in years after 1980.

This is what I got:

$6b=4.5b\cdot e^{k\cdot20}$

$k=\frac{\ln\frac{6b}{4.5b}}{20}$

Comment: Why $e^{k20}$ ?

Comment: @Cure 20 years from 1980 to 2000

Comment: 4.5 Billion as your 1980 population.  Carry that through, and the rest looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!

Let $P(t)$ the world population at time $t$. The assumption is that
$P'(t)=kP(t)$ which implies that $P(t)=P(t_0)e^{k(t-t_0)}$.

Take $t_0=1980$ and $t=2000$ then
$$P(2000)=6\cdot 10^9=P(1980)e^{k(2000-1980)}=4.5\cdot 10^9e^{20k}$$
which implies 
$$k=\frac{\ln(6/4.5)}{20}\approx 0.0143841\ [\mbox{year}]^{-1}.$$